# How to detect page scroll to the bottom of a long div?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a very long div (`height: 500px`), and I want to detect if user scrolled to the bottom of this div.

I have seen so many answers in the stackoverflow, almost all the answers mentioned `scrollTop`. However, in my simple example ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/trzavf2y/)), the `scrollTop` is always 0. After reading the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop), I realize maybe they are talking about scrollable div? But all I want is to detect whether user scrolled to the bottom of a normal div.

## Code

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <!-- This is the very very long div, which may be contained in some other divs -->
        <div></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**jQuery Code**

Currently, there is no scrollBottom function of jQuery. But, I have created a function that will tell whether we can see the bottom of a specific div element or not.

```
   let aDiv = document.getElementById("aDiv");
   $(document).scroll(function () {
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();
    var bottomVal = aDiv.offsetTop + aDiv.offsetHeight- windowHeight;
    let s = document.getElementById("txt");
    if(y>bottomVal && y< bottomVal + windowHeight){    s.innerHTML = "You can see bottom of aDiv";}
    else{   s.innerHTML = "Can't see bottom of aDiv"; }
  });
```

You can go through the following example. This might help you.
https://jsfiddle.net/q2smtvya/3/

**Update:** Added Vanilla JS Code. The only change will be the following JS Code

```
let aDiv = document.getElementById("aDiv");
window.onscroll = function(){
  var y = window.scrollY;
  var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
  var bottomVal = aDiv.offsetTop + aDiv.offsetHeight- windowHeight;
  let s = document.getElementById("txt");
  if(y>bottomVal && y< bottomVal + windowHeight){    s.innerHTML = "You can see bottom of aDiv";}
  else{   s.innerHTML = "Can't see bottom of aDiv"; }
};
```

You can go through the following example. This might help you.
https://jsfiddle.net/nrp7x61k/1/

Comment: As I stated in the problem, the scrollTop value of aDiv is always 0. I wonder why are you comparing y with other values.

Comment: I compare y with other values because this helps to detect whether the user scrolled to the bottom of a normal div or not. There is no predefined function that helps to detect this. If this doesn't explain your question, please tell me.

Comment: I get it. You are using `$(document)`'s `scrollTop` but not `aDiv`'s `scrollTop`. But if `aDiv` is contained in other divs, maybe we should use a `while` with `offsetParent` to get the right `offsetTop`?

Comment: You got it. It will work fine if `aDiv` is contained in other divs, we don't need to use `while` with `offsetParent`.

Comment: @am2505 do you know how to do this code with vanilla js?

Comment: @OscarVelandia I have updated the code for Vanilla JS. Hope this will help you.